# Use `nmcli` to add `IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES`

Tags: centos, nmcli

In my CentOS server, for compliance reason, I cant directly access the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` but I can use `nmcli` to configure that file.

My problem is that I need to add this line below to that file:

```
IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES="4566:1p44:e000:092b:0000:0000:0000:0000/64 4566:1p44:e000:092b:0000:0000:0000:0001/64"
```

But I cant find any `nmcli` command that adds this line to the file. Should I stop looking or is there a command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it work like this (I had to make some fake addresses for that purpose):

```
nmcli con mod enp0s3 ipv6.method manual ipv6.addresses "4566:1244:e000:092b:0000:0000:0000:0000/64"
nmcli con mod enp0s3 +ipv6.addresses "4566:1244:e000:092b:0000:0000:0000:1/64"
nmcli con show enp0s3 | grep ipv6.addresses
ipv6.addresses:                         4566:1244:e000:92b::/64, 4566:1244:e000:92b::1/64
```

You can also use nmtui which is easier but useless when you automate things.
I've tested it on RHEL 9.3 where these config files are deprecated entirely and I had no way of editing, but I think it should work for you.

Comment: WORKED PERFETCTLY! THANK YOU!